# Javascript Collision is not working

Tags: javascript, web, game-development

I have made a game like flappy bird . But here the bird/ball position is controlled by the mouse position.so when the wall collides with  ball the ball is pushed backward .if the mouse is moved while the ball is moving backward due to wall collision the ball passes through the wall.

```js
var context;
var screenWidth;
var screenHeight;
var ball;
var wall = [];
var gameStatus;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
var gameOver;
var running = false;
var raf;
var restartButton
var test_interval1;
var restartButton;
var score = 0;
var play;
var scoreBoard;
var score2;
var collision = false;
var n = 1500;


start();

function start() {
    gameIntialize();
    gameDraw();
    gameLoop();
    gameOver.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function Ball() {
    this.radius = 16;
    this.x = 25;
    this.y = screenHeight / 2;
    this.ballDraw = function() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, 16, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
    }
};


function Wall() {
    this.thickness = 10;
    this.wallPositionY = screenHeight;
    this.wallPositionX = screenWidth;
    this.spacing = 0;

    if (this.wallPositionY > 400 && this.wallPositionY <= 500) {
        this.spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
    } else if (this.wallPositionY > 500) {
        this.spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100) + 100);
    } else {
        this.spacing = 45;
    }

    this.heightFromTheTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.wallPositionY / 6 - 3 / 4 * this.wallPositionY) + 3 / 4 * this.wallPositionY);
    this.heightFromTheBottom = this.wallPositionY - (this.heightFromTheTop + this.spacing);
    this.speed = 6;



    this.draw = function() {

        context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        context.fillRect(this.wallPositionX, 0, this.thickness, this.heightFromTheTop);
        context.fillRect(this.wallPositionX, this.wallPositionY - this.heightFromTheBottom, this.thickness, this.heightFromTheBottom);
    }

    this.update = function() {
        this.wallPositionX = this.wallPositionX - this.speed;
    }

    this.offscreen = function() {
        if (this.wallPositionX < -this.thickness) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    this.check = function(ball) {
        if (ball.x + ball.radius > this.wallPositionX && ball.x - ball.radius < this.wallPositionX + this.thickness) {
            if (ball.y - ball.radius < this.heightFromTheTop || ball.y + ball.radius > this.heightFromTheTop + this.spacing) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
};


function gameIntialize() {
    var canvass = document.getElementById('canvas');

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    gameOver = document.getElementById('gameOver')
    restartButton = document.getElementById('restartButton');
    play = document.getElementById('play');
    scoreboard = document.getElementById('scoreboard');
    score2 = document.getElementById('score2');



    play.style.visibility = "visible";

    screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    screenHeight = window.innerHeight;


    canvas.width = screenWidth;
    canvas.height = screenHeight;

    ball = new Ball();
    wall.push(new Wall());

    drawScoreBoard();

    restartButton.addEventListener("click", reset);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeScreen, false);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (!running) {
            var xpos = e.clientX;
            var ypos = e.clientY;
            if (xpos >= screenWidth / 4) {
                ball.x = screenWidth / 4;
                ball.y = ypos;
        
            } else {
                {
                    ball.x = xpos;
                    ball.y = ypos;
                }
            }

        }
    });


}

function gameDraw() {
    context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    ball.ballDraw();

    for (var i = wall.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        wall[i].draw();
        wall[i].update();

        if (wall[i].offscreen()) {
            wall.splice(i, 1);
        }
        if (wall[i].check(ball)) {
         
          ball.x = wall[i].wallPositionX - ball.radius;

        }
    }


    raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(gameDraw);
}

function gameLoop() {
    test_interval1 = setInterval(function() {
        wall.push(new Wall());
    }, n);
    t = setInterval(function() {
        score++;
        drawScoreBoard();
    }, 1000);
}


function resizeScreen() {
    var newGameScreenWidth;
    var newGameScreenHeight;

    newGameScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    newGameScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;

    screenWidth = newGameScreenWidth;
    screenHeight = newGameScreenHeight;

    canvas.width = screenWidth;
    canvas.height = screenHeight;

    gameDraw();
}

function reset() {
    score = 0;
    start();
}

function gameOverR() {
    gameOver.style.visibility = "visible";
    play.style.visibility = "hidden";

    score2.innerHTML = "Score : " + score;

    gameOver.style.top = (screenHeight / 2) - 140 + "px";
    gameOver.style.left = (screenWidth / 2) - 160 + "px";

    clearInterval(test_interval1);
    clearInterval(t);

    while (wall.length >= 1) {
        wall.pop();
    }
}

function drawScoreBoard() {
    scoreboard.innerHTML = "Score : " + score;
}
```

```css
body{
  margin : 0px
}
#gameOver,#play{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
h1,h2,h3{
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.title{
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#restartButton{
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#restartButton:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}
#scoreboard{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>game-run</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section id="play">
        <h2 id="scoreboard"></h2>
    </section>
    <section id="gameOver">
        <h1 class="title">Game Over!</h1>
        <h2 id="score2"></h2>
        <h3 id="restartButton">Restart?</h3>
    </section>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>


</html>
```

how should i rectify this error ? any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would make the position of the ball a vector and use some acceleration and speed factors to make the ball move more fluid with the mouse. Checkout the [victor.js](http://victorjs.org/) library for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `mousemove` event listener. Onmousemove it sets this: `ball.x = xpos;ball.y = ypos;` without checking collisions. You need to edit it so the ball only moves to the mouse position if it is **not** colliding with anything. I'll leave the actual programming to you, but if you need any additional clarification, feel free to ask.